# Is it ok to not specify POST request within form since form's default request method is POST

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all, I am beginner in Laravel and as you know html form by default sends POST requests and wanted to ask if it is ok if I omit POST at the beginning of form tag since I want to send POST request to server The code:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'ToDoController@store' **I am not specifying type of request**]) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('text', 'Text', ['class' => 'awesome'])}}
    {{Form::text('text', '', ['class'=>'form-control' ,'style'=>'width:200px'])}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('text', 'Text', ['class' => 'awesome'])}}
    {{Form::text('text', '', ['class'=>'form-control' ,'style'=>'width:200px'])}}
</div>
{{Form::submit('Submit')}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Yes you can omit the request type if it's a POST. [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is OK to omit an attribute if the default is what you intend to carry out. However, you should note the following.

1. HTML forms by default sends 'GET' requests.
2. Form Collective which is a package used in Laravel Framework has by default set the method attribute of HTML forms to 'POST'.

So, the reason why your form is sending a 'POST' even when you didn't set the method attribute is because you are using Form Collective else your form would have defaulted to 'GET'.

Meanwhile, from the snippet you pasted:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'ToDoController@store' **I am not specifying type of request**]) !!}
```

Change that to:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ToDoController@store']) !!}
```

The `method` attribute is meant for specifying the kind of request...chiefly 'GET' or 'POST' while the `action` attribute is meant for specifying the Controller action that will handle the request.

Comment: sorry dear friend I wanted to understand why GET is default for form and found this:  it makes sense the GET is the default, as it specifies that method should be used for actions without side effects. Please can you clarify with your own words what this means. I hope for your answer

Comment: Side effects refers simply to the modification of some kind of state e.g writing to database, changing the value of a variable, writing some data to disk etc. In database operations context, `GET` is mostly used to `fetch` data and in most cases do not have side-effects while `POST` is mostly used to `insert`, `update` etc data. Of course `insert` and `update` actions change the state of data in the database. So, an educated guess would be that by default, we do not want side-effects, hence `GET` should be the default `form` method. I hope this is clear...?